# Vuejs: Using keep-alive (Or something similar) on a slot

Tags: vue.js

I've got a combination of tree hierarchy and tabs in vue. So far I've gotten the unfolding more or less working.

I need to remove things from the dom entirely when they're closed, because the data I'm talking about is large enough to bring a browser to its knees if it's all just left in the dom as `display:none`.

Take a look at this example:

```js
Vue.component('tabs', {
  template: '#tabs',
  data(){
    return {
      tabs: [],
      expanded:true,
      defaultExpanded:true,
      activeTab: null,
      hasChildren:false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.expanded = !this.expanded;
    },
    activate(tab) {
      if (this.activeTab) {
        this.activeTab.active = false;
      }
      tab.active = true;
      this.activeTab = tab;
    },
  },
  mounted(){
    for (i = 0; i < this.$slots.default.length; i++) {
      let t = this.$slots.default[i];
      if (t.componentOptions && t.componentOptions.tag == 'tab') {
        this.tabs.push(t.componentInstance);
      }
    }
    if (this.tabs.length) {
      this.activeTab = this.tabs[0];
      this.activeTab.active = true;
    }
    this.expanded = this.defaultExpanded;
  },
}); 

Vue.component('tab', {
  template: '#tab',
  data() {
    return {
      active: false,
    };
  },
  props: ['label'],
});

app = new Vue({
  'el': '#inst',
});
```

```html
<!-- templates -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="tabs">
  <div @click.stop="toggle">
    <h1><slot name="h" /></h1>
    <div v-show="expanded" class="children">
        <ul><li v-for="tab in tabs" @click.stop="activate(tab)">{{tab.label}}</li></ul>
      <div style="border:1px solid #F00"><slot /></div>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="tab">
  <strong v-show="active"><slot /></strong>
</script>

<!-- data -->
<tabs id="inst">
  <div slot="h">Woot</div>
  <tab label="label">
    <tabs>
      <div slot="h">Weet</div>
      <tab label="sub">Weetley</tab>
    </tabs>
  </tab>
  <tab label="label2">Woot3</tab>
</tabs>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
```

This works fine, but if I change the `v-show` to `v-if` for performance, it loses state, tab buttons stop showing - basically lots of stuff breaks.

The problem is that as soon as I add `v-if` to the `tab` template's slot the entire component is removed when it's closed. This means the parent component's `tabs` list is a completely different bunch of objects than the ones that show up when it's opened a second time.

This means I can't click on a label to open a tab, since the tabs will be different instances by the time I get to them, and all the tabs will default to closed every time I close and open the parent.

What I really need is something like `<keep-alive>` - where I could tell vue to keep the components alive in memory without rendering them to the dom. But when I add that the entire thing stops working. It seems like it really doesn't work on slots, only on individual components.

So. tl;dr: How do I maintain the state of mixed trees and tabs while using `v-if` to keep the dom light?

Comment: Looks like maybe you could make a computed that returns `tabs` when `expanded` is true, and an empty array when it's false. Use that in your `v-for`.

Comment: The reason I didn't do that is because I have to store the tabs twice (The slot won't render if there's no tabs, the tabs won't render if the `tabs` data says there aren't any) once on mount to see if they actually exist, and again on change. Wouldn't that make quite a hit on performance?

Comment: Also, the component state keeps resetting. If I select tab #2 and close and reopen the parent, tab #1 will be selected again.

Comment: The problem is that I can only get the tabs from `$slots.default`, and when the object is hidden with `v-if` that's empty, so it's a chicken-egg situation

Comment: Just so I understand: is the **behavior** of your snippet here wrong, but is correct if the `v-if` is replaced with `v-show`?

Comment: Yes exactly. If I used `v-show` it would work fine, but the performance wouldn't be sufficient

Comment: I can't wrap my head around what should be going on. I changed out `v-if` for `v-show` and the behavior was the same. You do have a missing `</tabs>` tag, tho.

Comment: Ah. Yeah the missing `</tabs>` is a mistake. I've added `v-show` to the question that demonstrates that it does work and maintains state when I use `v-show` instead of `v-if`

Comment: Does this work the way you are expecting? https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ZKPQpb?editors=1010

Comment: Closest I've seen yet, but the state is lost when closing them - if you open a tab and close the parent the state goes poof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on [Bert Evans' codepen](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ZKPQpb?editors=1010), I created a component that is just a slot. I made a `keep-alive`-wrapped dynamic component that `is` the slot-component when active and a blank component when not. Now there is no `v-if` and state is preserved in the children when you close and re-open the parent.

```js
console.clear();

Vue.component('keepableSlot', {
  template: '#keepable-slot'
});

Vue.component('tabs', {
  template: '#tabs',
  data() {
    return {
      tabs: [],
      expanded: true,
      activeTab: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addTab(tab) {
      this.tabs.push(tab)
    },
    toggle() {
      this.expanded = !this.expanded;
    },
    activate(tab) {
      if (this.activeTab) {
        this.activeTab.active = false;
      }
      tab.active = true;
      this.activeTab = tab;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    expanded(newValue) {
      console.log(this.$el, "expanded=", newValue);
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('tab', {
  props: ["label"],
  template: '#tab',
  data() {
    return {
      active: false
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$parent.$parent.addTab(this)
  }
});

app = new Vue({
  'el': '#inst',
});
```

```css
.clickable-tab {
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.toggler {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="tabs">
  <div>
    <h1 class="toggler" @click.stop="toggle">
      <slot name="h"></slot>
      (expanded={{expanded}})
    </h1>
    <keep-alive>
      <component :is="expanded && 'keepableSlot'">
        <div class="children">
          <ul>
            <li class="clickable-tab" v-for="tab in tabs" @click.stop="activate(tab)">{{tab.label}}</li>
          </ul>
          <div>
            <slot></slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </component>
    </keep-alive>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="keepable-slot">
  <div>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="tab">
  <strong>
    <component :is="active && 'keepableSlot'"><slot></slot></component>
  </div>
</script>

<!-- data -->
<tabs id="inst">
  <div slot="h">Woot</div>
  <tab label="label">
    <tabs>
      <div slot="h">Weet</div>
      <tab label="sub">Weetley</tab>
    </tabs>
  </tab>
  <tab label="label2">Woot3</tab>
</tabs>
```

Comment: That does look like the expected behavior. Thanks for swinging back around on this.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks Roy, Bert! I've already got a new problem but I'll make it a new question later if I can't figure it out myself

Comment: Nope! Just realised something and unticked - this is still using `v-show` on the tab. Any way to work around that? Theoretically this does heavily lower the dom overhead (Which is exactly what I need) but I'd like to get it down to the bear minimum

Comment: I have done the same keepable-slot trick in place of the v-show.

Comment: I'm still seeing both tabs when I hit run :(

Comment: Removed my half-baked "blank" idea; replaced with null. Now it works.

Comment: Now the state is reverting when you switch tabs! Is vue always this hard or do I just come up with weird use cases? :P **Edit:** But you're definitely on the right track, I think I've got a working variation on this now

Comment: This is a pretty weird use case. It would be more normal to have a data structure with Woot, Weet, etc. and to have Vue translate that into HTML. This is more like Bootstrap, where the data structure is embedded in the HTML.

Comment: I'd be interested to see how you address the reverting-state issue. I can't see why it's happening. The value of `expanded` seems to be unobservably changing (see updated code).

Comment: I've got it mostly working. I'll try to remember to send you a link if I don't need any more help with it